# How to set session_replication_role when writing a DynamicFrame in Glue

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, aws-glue

In order to run some data migration, I have to insert data without constraints.

I've found that you can run `SET session_replication_role = replica;` to do so in PostgresQL

How can I do the same in a Glue pyspark job? I've tried using `sampleQuery` but it did not work.

```
      source_connection = {
        "dbtable": table_name,
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "connectionName": connection_name,
        "stringtype": "unspecified",
        "sampleQuery": "SET session_replication_role = replica;"
      }

      # Write to RDS
      glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame = dyf,
        connection_type = "postgresql",
        connection_options = source_connection
      )
```

Comment: Seems like the `sessionInitStatement` in Spark dataframe (not Glue dynamicframe) can achieve what you want. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html